# How to specify member pointer to an array element?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-members

I have a library with function, which looks like this:

```
template<typename S1> void NastyFunction(S1 *array, EntryType S1::* member1);
```

So if I have an array of structs like:

```
struct TData {
  float a;
  float b[10];
};

TData dataArray[N];
```

I can apply `NastyFunction` to all `a`-s in `dataArray` using:

```
NastyFunction( dataArray, &TData::a );
```

How to apply this `NastyFunction` to all for example `b[7]`-s in `dataArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. While the entire array is a member of the class, its individual elements are not, so there is no way to make a member pointer point at them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without adding another level of indirection so that you just refer to class members, eg:

```
template<typename S1> void NastyFunction(S1 *array, EntryType* S1::* member1)
{
  EntityType value = *member1;
}

struct TData {
  float b[10];
  float* ref = &b[7];
};

TData *dataArray;
NastyFunction( dataArray, &TData::ref );
```

But it sounds like a clumsy solution.